# Your connection is not private (nginx, bluehost, google cloud and cloudflare)

Tags: nginx, debian, ssl-certificate, google-compute-engine, cloudflare

I host a site in compute engine in google cloud with Nginx on Debian, I use a Bluehost domain and a Cloudflare SSL.
My site web sometimes works and sometimes not and show me this message: Your connection is not private.
what is the solution?
example.com file:

```
    server {
    listen 80;
    listen [::]:80;
    server_name example.com www.example.com;
    return 302 https://$server_name$request_uri;
    }

    server {

    # SSL configuration

    listen 443 ssl http2;
    listen [::]:443 ssl http2;
    ssl        on;
    ssl_certificate         /etc/ssl/certs/cert.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key     /etc/ssl/private/key.pem;

    server_name example.com www.example.com;

    root /var/www/example.com/html;
    index index.html index.htm index.php;
    ssl_client_certificate /etc/ssl/certs/cloudflare.crt;
    ssl_verify_client on;


    location / {
            try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
    }

    location ~ \.php$ {           
        include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
        fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php7.0-fpm.sock;
    }
    }
```

Comment: This is most likely caused by either using the HTTP:// endpoint or you are referencing resources in your HTML that use HTTP:// . Make sure that everything uses HTTPS. Enable the debugger in your browser and review the networking tab.

Answer (score 1):

I think John H nailed it, seems you have a mixed content issue. You may end up having to edit as suggested, but I'd first recommend trying to enable "Automatic HTTPS Rewrites" on the Crypto tab. Other mixed content suggestions here, https://community.cloudflare.com/t/community-tip-fixing-mixed-content-errors/42476.

If you have more questions about Cloudflare, visit the Cloudflare Community, https://community.cloudflare.com/t/community-tip-welcome-stackoverflow-visitors/99529."